# Is there a way to automatically extend the range of a pivot table of a pivot table?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am currently trying to build a pivot table, using many pivot tables as the source of data. This is how I am currently doing this:

1. I have raw data that I convert into a table using ctrl-T. This is so that I can reference the Table rather than a fixed range when I make pivot tables, so that additional rows to the raw data are automatically accounted for.
2. I create the multiple pivot tables, referencing the created table.
3. I create a pivot table using the existing pivot tables as the data by pressing Alt-D-P and selecting multiple data ranges.

Here's where I am having the problem: When pressing Alt-D-P, I tried using the PivotTables themselves as the range using the excel naming convention 'Sheet1'!PivotTable1, etc. It does not accept them. It only seems to accept fixed ranges. This is fine until I have to update the data and it comes with additional rows/variables unaccounted for in the fixed ranges.

How can I create a pivot table that automatically extends its range when the data it pulls from are also pivot tables?

Comment: If you have office365 you may want to use FILTER function to get dynamic spill range of required data. This will update/adjust range live.

Comment: For semi-automatic updating (on opening of file) or auto updating (macro) please read here https://www.pivot-table.com/2014/10/15/automatically-refresh-a-pivot-table/

Comment: If you are using Excel 2010+ for Windows, it might be better to do this in Power Query/Power Pivot. Power Query could create your initial pivot tables and then combine them into a table that can be loaded into your PowerPivot data model. That data model can then be placed into a Power Pivot - pivot table. Another approach is to put the initial tables into the data model and create relationships between them, then use Power Pivot to create the pivot from those. Everything would update with one refresh.

Comment: To take the Power BI path above, you could repose this question with a description of your inputs and your expected outcomes. Then someone can propose whether that can be done simply by Power Pivot or a combination of Power Query and Power Pivot. Remember to state your Excel version (and hopefully, it is not Excel for Mac.)